# Serverless WSGI not working in pipelines (works locally)

Tags: django, wsgi, serverless

I have the following steps configured in our bitbucket pipeline:

```
          # Configure Serverless
          - cp requirements.txt src/requirements.txt
          - serverless config credentials --provider aws --key ${AWS_KEY} --secret ${AWS_SECRET}
          - cd src
          - sls plugin install -n serverless-python-requirements
          - sls plugin install -n serverless-wsgi
          - sls plugin install -n serverless-dotenv-plugin

          # Perform the Deployment
          - sls deploy --stage ${LOCAL_SERVERLESS_STAGE}
          - sls deploy list functions

          # Prep the environment
          - sls wsgi manage --command "migrate"
          - sls wsgi manage --command "collectstatic --noinput"
```

When the pipeline runs, the `sls deploy` works perfectly fine and the deployed function operates exactly as expected. The `sls wsgi manage` commands throw the following error, however:

```
  Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
 
  Function "undefined" doesn't exist in this Service
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          linux
     Node Version:              11.13.0
     Framework Version:         2.35.0
     Plugin Version:            4.5.3
     SDK Version:               4.2.2
     Components Version:        3.8.2
```

I can run the `sls wsgi manage` commands locally (with same AWS keys) without issue. The issue only seems to happen in the pipeline.

Thoughts?

#### Additional Information

**serverless.yml**

```
service: service-api

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-wsgi
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin

custom:
  wsgi:
    app: service.wsgi.application
    packRequirements: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerFile: ./serverless-dockerfile
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    pythonBin: python3
    useDownloadCache: false
    useStaticCache: false

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - s3:GetObject
        - s3:PutObject
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::*"
  # vpc:
  #   securityGroupIds:
  #     - 
  #   subnetIds:
  #     - 
  #     - 
  #     - 
  #     - 

functions:
  app:
    handler: wsgi.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: "ANY {proxy+}"
    timeout: 600
```

**Output of Serverless deploy list functions**

```
+ sls deploy list functions
(node:1127) ExperimentalWarning: queueMicrotask() is experimental.
(node:1127) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
(node:1127) ExperimentalWarning: The dns.promises API is experimental
Serverless: Deprecation warning: Detected ".env" files. In the next major release variables from ".env" files will be automatically loaded into the serverless build process. Set "useDotenv: true" to adopt that behavior now.
            More Info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#LOAD_VARIABLES_FROM_ENV_FILES
Serverless: DOTENV: Loading environment variables from .env:
...STUFF HERE...
Serverless: Deprecation warning: CLI options definitions were upgraded with "type" property (which could be one of "string", "boolean", "multiple"). Below listed plugins do not predefine type for introduced options:
             - ServerlessWSGI for "port", "host", "disable-threading", "num-processes", "ssl", "command", "file"
            Please report this issue in plugin issue tracker.
            Starting with next major release, this will be communicated with a thrown error.
            More Info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#CLI_OPTIONS_SCHEMA
Serverless: Configuration warning at 'functions.app.events[1].http': value 'ANY {proxy+}' does not satisfy pattern /^(?:\*|(GET|POST|PUT|PATCH|OPTIONS|HEAD|DELETE|ANY) (\/\S*))$/i
Serverless:  
Serverless: Learn more about configuration validation here: http://slss.io/configuration-validation
Serverless:  
Serverless: Deprecation warning: Starting with next major, Serverless will throw on configuration errors by default. Adapt to this behavior now by adding "configValidationMode: error" to service configuration
            More Info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#CONFIG_VALIDATION_MODE_DEFAULT
Serverless: Deprecation warning: Starting with version 3.0.0, following property will be replaced:
              "provider.iamRoleStatements" -> "provider.iam.role.statements"
            More Info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#PROVIDER_IAM_SETTINGS
Serverless: Deprecation warning: Resolution of lambda version hashes was improved with better algorithm, which will be used in next major release.
            Switch to it now by setting "provider.lambdaHashingVersion" to "20201221"
            More Info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#LAMBDA_HASHING_VERSION_V2
Serverless: Listing functions and their last 5 versions:
Serverless: -------------
Serverless: app: $LATEST, 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was pretty mundane. Serverless 2.32+ introduced some change that broke the pipeline. Reverting to version 2.31.0 resolved the issue.

Comment: `npm install serverless@2.32.0 -g` to install it globally, installing locally doesn't affect anything, at least in my tests.